# Compare a column across different timelines?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with variables Date and stage,

[image: it will look like this..]

now in the next week, i want the same date's previous week stage and also a comparison column which shows the conditions "Same" or "Different"

[image: here is how it should look]

and also another column that shows the moment of stages

[image: here is an example of it]

A DAX formula would be really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: i haven't really got any idea about how to implement it.. i thought of getting multiple measures.. but i don't know where to even start. And yet, this is a required solution for me which i have explained to you through excel.